# Counting Records in Linux Files Excluding Some Files

Tags: linux, awk, count, wc

I have to count the number of records I have in 6 files, each file contains 4 million records (the count should be as fast as possible), however there is another file with a similar name which should be omitted.

fileSales_1.txt   (4 million records)

fileSales_2.txt   (4 million records)

fileSales_3.txt   (4 million records)

fileSales_4.txt   (4 million records)

fileSales_5.txt   (4 million records)

fileSales_6.txt   (4 million records)

fileSales_unique.txt (24 million records)

I'm counting the logs with the following command: `awk 'END {pint NR}' fileSales_*.txt`

However, in doing so, the fileSales_unique.txt archive also counts, giving a total of 48 million records

Could you help me with an instruction which only counts the number of records for files 1 to 6?
The result should be 24 million records, awk 'END {pint NR}' fileSales_(1 to 6).txt

Comment: `wc -l fireSales_[1-6].txt` etc.?

Comment: You can either have a list of excluded file names within awk or set you glob pattern at the shell level.

Comment: If you know that you have 6 files with 4 million records each why do you need `awk` to compute the total (24 millions)? Note that using `awk` to count lines is a bit overkill. `wc` is probably a better utility.

Comment: Is each record on 1 line or do your files contain multi-line records? If multi-line, how can you tell one record from the next? Post a [mcve]...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have these files (using `wc` to show both file names and size):

```
 4000000 fileSales_1.txt
 4000000 fileSales_2.txt
 4000000 fileSales_3.txt
 4000000 fileSales_4.txt
 4000000 fileSales_5.txt
 4000000 fileSales_6.txt
 24000000 fileSales_unique.txt
 24000000 fileSales_unique_also.txt
 72000000 total
```

There are *many* ways to achieve your goal, but two primary ones:

1. Use a glob that only includes the desired files;
2. Use an exclusion list or pattern that excludes the the undesired files.

Inclusion glob:

1. `wc -l fileSales_{1..6}.txt`
2. `wc -l fileSales_?.txt`
3. `wc -l fileSales_[1-6].txt`

Any of those:

```
$ wc -l fileSales_[1-6].txt  
 4000000 fileSales_1.txt
 4000000 fileSales_2.txt
 4000000 fileSales_3.txt
 4000000 fileSales_4.txt
 4000000 fileSales_5.txt
 4000000 fileSales_6.txt
 24000000 total
```

(Same concept applies to `awk`)

Or, maintain a `skip` array in Bash:

```
skip=( *_unique* )
to_cnt_files=()
for fn in fileSales*.txt; do 
    [[ "${skip[@]/$fn/}" != "${skip[@]}" ]] && continue
    to_cnt_files+=( "$fn" )
done
```

Then your method works:

```
awk 'END{print NR}' $(printf "%s\n" "${to_cnt_files[@]}")
# 24000000
```

Know that `wc` in this case will be *monumentally* faster than awk likely...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments you do not need `awk` to count the records. You can use `wc`:

```
wc -l fileSales_?.txt
```

This will accept all filenames which start with `fileSales_` then one symbol and then `.txt`. If you want to limit to numbers you can use:

```
wc -l fileSales_[1-6].txt
```

The same with `awk`:

```
awk 'END {print NR}' fileSales_?.txt
```